# R dplyr - rollmean using group by columns

Tags: r

I have a data frame as below :

(find image if data is not as per format)

```
Sample Data                     
date    id  name    loc mean    count   mean
9/6/2016    kar1    AAA 100004  0   1   
9/8/2016    kar1    AAA 100004  0   3   
9/9/2016    kar1    AAA 100004  0   4   
9/10/2016   kar1    AAA 100004  0   5   
9/11/2016   kar1    AAA 100004  0   6   
9/12/2016   kar1    AAA 100004  0   7   
9/13/2016   kar1    AAA 100004  0   8   
9/14/2016   kar1    AAA 100004  0   9   
9/7/2016    blr1    BBB 100004  0   2
```

am trying to calculate((7 day rolling mean)) 3 day rolling average (previous 3 day and following 3 day) 
on count field based on id,name,loc but results are not as expected.

find below code:

```
fnrollmean <- function(x) rollmean(df$count,7,na.pad=TRUE,align="center")

rollmeandf <- df %>% group_by(id,name,loc) %>% arrange(id,name,loc) %>% mutate(funs=fnrollmean(df$count))
```

I get error :

> Error in eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos) :    incompatible size
>   (9), expecting 8 (the group size) or 1

If I just do :

```
test2 <- df %>% mutate(funs=fnrollmean(df$count))
```

it works but calculates by considering all disease which is wrong.

Please let me know if am missing something or any work around.

Expected results:

```
date    id  name    loc mean    count   mean
9/6/2016    kar1    AAA 100004  0   1   NA
9/8/2016    kar1    AAA 100004  0   3   NA
9/9/2016    kar1    AAA 100004  0   4   NA
9/10/2016   kar1    AAA 100004  0   5   4.8
9/11/2016   kar1    AAA 100004  0   6   6
9/12/2016   kar1    AAA 100004  0   7   NA
9/13/2016   kar1    AAA 100004  0   8   NA
9/14/2016   kar1    AAA 100004  0   9   NA
9/7/2016    blr1    BBB 100004  0   2   NA
```

[image: sample data in image]

Thanks

Comment: Your `fnrollmean` function needs to use the 'x' argument that is passed into it (instead of `df$count`). In your call to `mutate`, you should use `count`, not `df$count`. But even making these changes still produces an error. I'm not familiar enough with the _zoo_ package to comment further.

Answer (score 5):

To use `mutate`, you must have a window function that returns the same length vector as the vector(s) that are input to the function (or return a scalar which will be coerced to a vector of that length filled with the scalar value). The issue is that your `fnrollmean` does not and hence the error. Notice that the same type of error will remain even after following jdobre's comments with your posted input data because your second group `(blr1, BBB, 100004)` has only `1` row. Therefore, modify `fnrollmean` as:

```
library(zoo)
fnrollmean <- function (x) {
  if (length(x) < 7) {
    rep(NA,length(x)) 
  } else {
    rollmean(x,7,align="center",na.pad=TRUE)
  }
}
```

Note that we followed jdobre's comment to use `x` instead of `df$count` within the function. Then (again following jdobre's comment to use `count` instead of `df$count` when calling `fnrollmean` within `mutate`):

```
library(dplyr)
result <- df %>% group_by(id,name,loc) %>% 
                 mutate(rollavg=fnrollmean(count))
```

gives:

```
print(result)
##Source: local data frame [9 x 7]
##Groups: id, name, loc [2]
##
##       date     id   name    loc  mean count  rollavg
##     <fctr> <fctr> <fctr>  <int> <int> <int>    <dbl>
##1  9/6/2016   kar1    AAA 100004     0     1       NA
##2  9/8/2016   kar1    AAA 100004     0     3       NA
##3  9/9/2016   kar1    AAA 100004     0     4       NA
##4 9/10/2016   kar1    AAA 100004     0     5 4.857143
##5 9/11/2016   kar1    AAA 100004     0     6 6.000000
##6 9/12/2016   kar1    AAA 100004     0     7       NA
##7 9/13/2016   kar1    AAA 100004     0     8       NA
##8 9/14/2016   kar1    AAA 100004     0     9       NA
##9  9/7/2016   blr1    BBB 100004     0     2       NA
```

Comment: If it worked, you should accept this answer so that people know the question has been answered. :)